# How to address comments/questions to the site's operatives?

Tags: support

Is this the preferred page to comment or ask questions about management issues (editing, deleting, culture, etc.) with the Physics-stackexchange.com site?  Or is there a more direct path to communicate with the administrators/monitors/managers?

Answer (score 5):

[With 15 rep you can flag posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) with a custom flag reason, and there is always the [**contact us**](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page to contact the operators of the Stack Exchange network.

In your current rep range you can post to meta but not issue flags, so your choices are limited.

---

I see that you have only one post on the main site, and it has been deleted---by me, none-the-less---some I'm going to guess that this is the cause of your question.

Stack Exchange sites are a bit different from a lot of other sites on the internet.
We use a "question & answer" model instead of a "threaded conversation" model, and you should not post a followup question "under" an existing question. Those "under" posts are called "answers" and should only be used to *answer the question*.

If you have a different question you should use the "[ASK QUESTION](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)" button at the top of the page. You can certainly link to the previous question to explain your motivation if you think that is helpful (keeping in mind that [until you have 10 rep you can only put two links in a single post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user)).

Answer (score 5):

> Is this the preferred page to comment or ask questions about management issues (editing, deleting, culture, etc.) with the Physics-stackexchange.com site?

Yes, this is exactly the place to ask general questions about why posts are edited or deleted and about the site culture, because you can get the answers from other users of the site. You don't need to contact an administrator or moderator.

If you think someone's post is inappropriate, or you have reason to believe another member is engaging in behavior that is not allowed, you should generally flag the relevant post instead of posting here on meta. Flagging requires that you have 15 reputation.

> Or is there a more direct path to communicate with the administrators/monitors/managers?

You should know that there are two levels of oversight for Stack Exchange sites. The [moderators](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) are members of the site who have been elected to clean up obsolete or gibberish posts, handle disputes, and so on. The flags I mentioned above are processed by the moderators, so if you want to bring a post to our attention, flagging is the way to do it.

Above the moderators are the Stack Exchange team. Under most circumstances, you don't need to contact them directly. If you do need to for some reason, you can use the [contact page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/contact).